# Using git flow, it didn't change the master branch. Is that right?

Tags: merge, branch, release, git-flow

Why wasn't my master branch changed after I executed this command line?

```
git flow release finish v0.0.1
# 1. Write merge message
# 2. Write tag name and message
git push --tags
```

Using [git flow command(git flow)](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow), I tried to follow their strategy. My project's master branch wasn't changed by executing some command lines (Branch name release number). It only changed the develop branch and created a tag on the master branch. It did not merge the master branch.

```
git flow release finish v0.0.1
# 1. Write merge message
# 2. Write tag name and message
git push --tags
```

The log below is the result of the above command lines:

```
$ git flow release finish v0.0.1
```

> Summary of actions:

> - Release branch 'release/v0.0.1' has been merged into 'master'

> - The release was tagged 'v0.0.1'

- Release tag 'v0.0.1' has been back-merged into 'develop'
- Release branch 'release/v0.0.1' has been locally deleted; it has been remotely deleted from 'origin'
- You are now on branch 'develop'

  $ git push --tags

> Username for 'https://github.com': drake-jin
> Password for 'https://drake-jin@github.com':
> Counting the number of objects : 1, complete.
> Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 188 bytes | 0 bytes/s, complete.
> Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
> To [https://github.com/drake-jin/♥](https://github.com/drake-jin/%E2%99%A5)

> - [new tag]         v0.0.1 -> v0.0.1

[image: git flow official document said that it will merge release branch and master branch]

This picture is part of an officially provided document from [git flow repository](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/why-arent-you-using-git-flow/).

I am not clear what this part of this picture means:

> Boom. git-flow pulls from origin, merges the release branch into master, tags the release and back-merges everything back into develop before removing the release branch.

This part said that master branch is merged with release branch. Isn't it?

Actually, I can't still understand it. Why isn't my master branch changed? It just has a tag.

Answer (score 2):

Finish release will both merge the release into `master` and into `develop`. But it is still all happened locally - Could it be that you didn't push it to the origin?

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have 'simple' push enabled, the push will only push the current branch.  In the case of doing a push after a `git flow release finish`, that is the develop branch.  Do `git config --global --get push.default` to check your setting, if it is **simple**, you need to git checkout master and then issue another `git push`